# Panel data: When can I used random effects instead of fixed effects? Are control variables necessary?

Tags: panel-data, econometrics, random-effects-model, fixed-effects-model

I have panel data for individuals in an economy that experienced fluctuations in employment levels. I also have some health information for these individuals, BMI, self-rated health etc.,

My question is this, my dataset is quite small, (1500 people wave one, 1000 wave two, 700 people wave three), I am aware that fixed effects regressions can really cut down the number of individuals I can examine observations in comparison to random effects. Hausman tests aside, are there any theoretical good arguments for using a random effects model in the case where fixed effects decreases the number of individuals analysed to just a handful of people?

Similarly, in a fixed effects regression is it necessary to include control variables? After all, surely this kind of regression is only examining within individual variation, such that control variables are not necessary?

Any and all insight is greatly appreciated,

Comment: Why (and how) does a fixed effects regresson reduce the number of individuals?

Comment: Fixed-effects models are looking at the determinants of within-subject variability. If there is no variability within a subject, there is nothing to examine. If I am analyzing something that rarely changes across time, or if very few individuals are in a binary group that I would like to examine, there wouldn’t be many cases left for a fixed effects analysis. Thus some of the sample will be dropped from the analysis. Which is what I meant by "reduce the number of individuals (in my sample)". I am aware that other techniques, like random effects or xtreg, fe, won’t cost so many cases.

Comment: `xtreg, fe` is just the Stata command to perform a fixed effects panel regression. I don't think the number of individuals is reduced by an FE model, rather variables can drop out of the regression because they are not estimable. A variable is not estimable if there is no variation for it and that can be due to the within transformation (as you explain) but it would need to be so for all individuals. If just some individuals have a constant value for the specific variable, the respective observation will still be used (as it carries information about the other variables).

Comment: Thank you for your comment, although I must admit to some confusion still on the place of control variables in a fixed effects regression...

Comment: Just run a FE regression and look at the summary output of the result. Usually, the number of individuals used in the estimation are printed and you will see if any coefficents are not estimable (drop out of the estimation).